# Python- Check in the CSV file the Header value and data value is equal

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I just have few queries regarding the CSV files.

**-All the values are equal to Header.**

For Ex:-

abc.csv file contain

```
RollNO,Name,Age
1,Abc,15
2,Def,18
```

some times what's happening the file is coming like this

```
RollNO,Name,Age
1,Abc,15
2,Def,18,blabla,21
```

In this case the value are greater then the header. So how can i check this thing.

**-Check Blank Header**

***aaa.csv***

```
RollNO,Name,Age, ,Address
```

I have to check that there should be no blank in the header.

**-Check that there is no special character in the header.**

***bbb.csv***

```
Rol$lNO,Name,Age,Address
```

I have to check this thing also that the header should not contain the special character.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Format your literal data properly

Comment: I have tried but its not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re    
csvfile = open('abc.csv','r')
csv = [line.split(',') for line in csvfile.readlines()]
```

### Problem #1: Check if a data row is longer than the header row:

```
for i in csv[1:]:
    if len(i) > len(csv[0]):
        print("found a data row that is longer then the header row.")
```

### Problem #2: Check if there's an empty header item:

```
blank = re.compile(r'\s*')
for i in csv[0]:
    if blank.match(i).end() == len(i):
        print("found an empty header item")
```

### Problem #3: Check if there's any special characters in the header:

```
charset = re.compile(r'\w*')
for i in csv[0]:
    if charset.match(i).end() != len(i):
        print("found a header item that contains special characters.")
```